# Not able to Fetch nytimes data for Technology Section using their official API

Tags: flutter, api, web-services, dart, webservice-client

I am trying to use nytimes api for fetching technology news section and using that on my web app but `_articles.length` is throwing me error of `noSuchMethodError` I tried running it with sports and other sections it works and but it throws error for technology section and I only want that for my project, and I also have tried the url on postman it works fine for technology there but not in flutter and dart please help,

I am getting below error in vscode console for using technology section,

```
Error: NoSuchMethodError: 'length'
method not found
Receiver: null
Arguments: []
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:60362/dart_sdk.js:5061:11)
    at api_service.APIService.new.fetchArticlesBySection (http://localhost:60362/packages/devcom/services/api_service.dart.lib.js:43:23)
    at fetchArticlesBySection.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:60362/dart_sdk.js:38640:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:60362/dart_sdk.js:38511:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:60362/dart_sdk.js:33713:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:60362/dart_sdk.js:34265:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:60362/dart_sdk.js:34303:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:60362/dart_sdk.js:34151:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:60362/dart_sdk.js:34172:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:60362/dart_sdk.js:38778:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:60362/dart_sdk.js:38784:13)
    at http://localhost:60362/dart_sdk.js:34519:9
```

I dont know why its throwing this  null error
this is my dart file where I have used length function at last lines of code check below

```
import 'package:devcom/models/article_model.dart';
import 'package:devcom/services/api_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:devcom/utils/responsive.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class ExploreSection extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExploreSectionState createState() => _ExploreSectionState();
}

class _ExploreSectionState extends State<ExploreSection> {
  List<Article> _articles = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchArticles();
  }

  _fetchArticles() async {
    List<Article> articles =
        await APIService().fetchArticlesBySection("technology");
    setState(() {
      _articles = articles;
    });
  }

  _buildArticlesGrid(MediaQueryData mediaQuery) {
    List<GridTile> tiles = [];
    _articles.forEach((article) {
      tiles.add(_buildArticleTile(article, mediaQuery));
    });
    return Padding(
      padding: responsivePadding(mediaQuery),
      child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: responsiveNumGridTiles(mediaQuery),
        mainAxisSpacing: 30.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 30.0,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: tiles,
      ),
    );
  }

  _launchURL(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  _buildArticleTile(Article article, MediaQueryData mediaQuery) {
    return GridTile(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => _launchURL(article.url),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: responsiveImageHeight(mediaQuery),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                ),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(article.imageUrl),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: responsiveTitleHeight(mediaQuery),
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                ),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black12,
                    offset: Offset(0, 1),
                    blurRadius: 6.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Text(
                article.title,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
                maxLines: 2,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 80.0),
          Center(
            child: Text(
              'The New York Times\nTop Tech Articles',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                letterSpacing: 1.5,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 15.0),
          if (_articles.length > 0)         // the error causing line is this ig 
            _buildArticlesGrid(mediaQuery)
          else
            Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my `api_service.dart`:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:devcom/models/article_model.dart';

class APIService {
  final String _baseUrl = 'api.nytimes.com';
  static const String API_KEY = 'MY_API_KEY_HERE';

  Future<List<Article>> fetchArticlesBySection(String section) async {
    Map<String, String> parameters = {
      'api-key': API_KEY,
    };
    Uri uri = Uri.https(
      _baseUrl,
      "/svc/topstories/v2/$section.json",
      parameters,
    );
    try {
      var response = await http.get(uri);
      Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
      List<Article> articles = [];
      data['results'].forEach(
        (articleMap) => articles.add(Article.fromMap(articleMap)),
      );
      return articles;
    } catch (err) {
      throw err.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

In the above code only CirclularProgressIndicator() is executing irrespective's of the condition.
I have followed this tutorial from youtube [source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjlnT2ieh70&t=239s)

This is my article model class dart file:

```
class Article {
  final String title;
  final String byline;
  final String url;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String publishedDate;
  final String summary;

  Article({
    required this.title,
    required this.byline,
    required this.url,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.publishedDate,
    required this.summary,
  });

  factory Article.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Article(
      title: map['title'],
      byline: map['byline'],
      url: map['url'],
      imageUrl: map['multimedia'].length > 0
          ? map['multimedia'][3]['url']
          : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504711434969-e33886168f5c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80',
      publishedDate: map['published_date'],
      summary: map['abstract'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can u print length in console?

Comment: @AmitSingh OP will get the exact same error.

Comment: @AmitSingh first I tried printing `_articles.length` in scaffold it throws 
> This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.
Try checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void. so I tried using print `outside scaffold` and in the `buildcontext` but that too prints nothing any other thing which should I try

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely causing your error:

```
 List<Article> articles =
        await APIService().fetchArticlesBySection("technology");
```

Make sure that it's not null. The error you are getting is produced whenever you call an operation\method on a list, like foreach, because dart checks for it's length first, and if the list is null, you get your error.

this however should solve your problem, by checking if it's null or not before calling.length:

```
if(_articles != null) 
    _articles.length > 0 
       ?  _buildArticlesGrid(mediaQuery)
       :  Center(
       child: CircularProgressIndicator(),),
```

Comment: I tried using your code its showing me The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true.
Remove the condition.
but that does not change anything, it just shows as usual CircularProgressIndicator any other solution sir,

Comment: If you get the circular indiciator, it means that your error is gone. And that your list is empty.

Comment: Make sure your list is not empty.

Comment: Yeah its working now thanks I checked it by using another section rather than technology

Comment: hey but I am not able to work with technology section it isn't just fetching what's the problem with that can you help with that other section just works fine I tried using sports and arts section.Actually my main motto of using this nytimes api was to fetch technology section news but that only isnt working can you please help

Comment: Post the response for the technolgy API, maybe you have a typo during parsing, that's the most logical explanation, if everything else is working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237244/discussion-between-mithson-and-huthaifa-muayyad).